# Cookies not available in subdomain

Tags: cookies, subdomain

I am using Spring Boot and While I am able to set the cookie on the server, it is available in the response on the browser, however it is not submitted in the further request, and reason seems to be a sub-domain issue. I will detail it with exact issue and content

Requesting Page: http://stgapi.py.com 
it makes a API call -> http://secure.stgapi.py.com

Cookies is set with 
Domain-> .py.com Also tried with .stgapi.py.com
path-> /

This is visible in the browser, however in the subsequent call to 
http://secure.stgapi.py.com the cookies are not submitted

and hence re-login is requested and enters an infinite loop of login and failure.

Any help is much appreciated, entire web says this is how it works, not able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

After much brainstorming, figured out that we need to set 
*("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")*

And client(User-Agent) should also send **withCredrentials:true**

Further *("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")* should not be set to "*" and only one value(origin) is supported.

Reason: Being the above example is considered to be CORS request and not the way it looks at the very first place.